# I want all links in my app to open with a specific intent

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, deep-linking

so in my app I have created an activity that only contains webview and this activity task is to disallow the user from opening any other link within the webview other than the opened link.

the app should only use this webview activity to open all the links in the app.

currently when I open any link in the app the intent selector appears to choose between other web browsers and my activity

how can I make it so that any link in my app automatically opens in the webview activity without prompting the user to select between browsers just like how facebook messenger open links in it, it opens links in an activity called BrowserLiteActivity under com.facebook.browser.lite.

My Intent Filter

```
<activity
        android:name=".InternalWebView.InternalWebviewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_internal_webview"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true"
            android:label="someLabel">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:scheme=" "/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Edit: to be more clear here is everything related to the issue

InternalWebViewActivity.java

```
package com.example.example.InternalWebView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import com.example.example.R;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class InternalWebviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.webview)
    WebView wv;
    private io.reactivex.Observable timer = io.reactivex.Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String data = intent.getData().toString();
        InternalWebViewClient internalWebViewClient = new InternalWebViewClient(data);

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(internalWebViewClient);
        this.timer
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe((mSec) -> {
                        String wvURL = wv.getUrl();
                        if (!wvURL.contains(internalWebViewClient.url))
                            wv.loadUrl(data);
                });


        wv.loadUrl(data);
    }
}
```

InternalWebClient.java

```
package com.example.example.InternalWebView;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class InternalWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public String url;
    public InternalWebViewClient(String url){
        URL u = null;
        try {
            u = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.url = url.substring(url.indexOf(u.getHost()));
        this.url = this.url.substring(this.url.indexOf(".")+1);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains(this.url)){
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

just to get how the Activity looks like

webview_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Note: Facebook Messenger doesn't require changing the scheme to open the links in their activity.**

Comment: the same activity inside the current webview? or different activity with a new webview?

Comment: Your scheme is shared between your app and other apps that can browse web-based content (http/https). If you were making your scheme something for your app only (like your package name, the name of your company etc), then the links would only be opened through your app. If you *need* to open http/https links, then either 1. start the intent manually (from within your app, activity to activity) or 2. accept the way Android works, and that other apps can also handle http/https web browsing

Comment: @NSimon adding a scheme for my app only seems like something I can try to do thanks for explaining how things work

Comment: I can't really understand your english

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:This answer is not satisfying enough if you don't want to change the scheme as in my case now.

So as @NSimon mentioned in the question comments his solution worked fine

Here is a sample link that is send to the app through an API: "example://www.stackoverflow.com"

Here is the code:

the activity part in AndroidManifist.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".InternalWebView.InternalWebviewActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_internal_webview"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <intent-filter
        android:autoVerify="true"
        android:label="somelable">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="example"/>
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

InternalWebViewActivity.java

```
package com.example.example.InternalWebView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import com.example.example.R;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class InternalWebviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.webview)
    WebView wv;
    private io.reactivex.Observable timer = io.reactivex.Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String data = intent.getData().toString().replace("example://","http://");
        InternalWebViewClient internalWebViewClient = new InternalWebViewClient(data);

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(internalWebViewClient);

        //lazy and efficient method to handle url changed using javascript only
        this.timer
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe((mSec) -> {
                        String wvURL = wv.getUrl();
                        if (!wvURL.contains(internalWebViewClient.url))
                            wv.loadUrl(data);
                });


        wv.loadUrl(data);
    }
}
```

InternalWebViewClient.java

```
package com.example.example.InternalWebView;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class InternalWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public String url;
    public InternalWebViewClient(String url){
        URL u = null;
        try {
            u = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //just to ignore stuff like www. being redirected to m. for mobile
        this.url = url.substring(url.indexOf(u.getHost()));
        this.url = this.url.substring(this.url.indexOf(".")+1);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains(this.url)){
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

hope this helps someone.